# SQL Server - Inner join: incorrect syntax

Tags: sql-server, inner-join

I am trying to inner join two tables in SQL server. I have a sintax error, and I believe it is linked to the lines of codes I used to GROUP BY in the first table:

```
SELECT TOP (10000) MAX (PlanID) AS [PlanID]
  ,MAX (InfoID) AS [InfoID]
  ,MAX (Comp) AS [Comp] 
  ,MAX (CompName) AS [CompName]
  ,MAX (GuidID) AS [GuidID]
  ,MAX (Object) AS [Object]
  ,OrderID
  ,CurrencyShort

  FROM [dbo].[Plant] as Plimp
  WHERE [CompName] NOT LIKE 'BB%'
  and InfoID < 196673
  and InfoID > 185679
  GROUP BY (InfoID)
  order by InfoID desc

  INNER JOIN [dbo].[Order] as Ord
  ON Plimp.InfoID = Ord.InfoID
```

Error message:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 19
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INNER'.

---

Second attempt:

```
SELECT TOP (10000) MAX (PlanID) AS [PlanID]
  ,MAX (InfoID) AS [InfoID]
  ,MAX (Comp) AS [Comp] 
  ,MAX (CompName) AS [CompName]
  ,MAX (GuidID) AS [GuidID]
  ,MAX (Object) AS [Object]
  ,OrderID  /*field from [dbo].[Order]*/
  ,CurrencyShort /*field from [dbo].[Order]*/
FROM   [dbo].[PlanningImplant] AS Plimp
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Order] AS Ord
           ON Plimp.InfoID = Ord.InfoID
WHERE  [CompName] NOT LIKE 'BB%'
   AND Plimp.InfoID < 196673
   AND Plimp.InfoID > 185679
GROUP  BY ( Plimp.InfoID )
ORDER  BY Plimp.InfoID DESC
```

Error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
>   Invalid column name 'InfoID'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
>   Invalid column name 'InfoID'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
>   Invalid column name 'CompName'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
>   Invalid column name 'InfoID'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
>   Invalid column name 'InfoID'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
>   Invalid column name 'InfoID'.
>   Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Ambiguous column name 'InfoID'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 20
>   Invalid column name 'InfoID'.

---

Note:
",[InfoID]" column in "[dbo].[Plant]" originally presents duplicates, which I eliminate in the original table with "WHERE [CompName] NOT LIKE 'BB%'". The problem here is that this condition is after the Inner Join, but I can't put it before, or I get an error anyway... Maybe I should use some parenthesis?

Comment: you should first read documentation to know where inner joins are placed :) in a query

Comment: I understand, but that is what I did and anyway I got the same error, just repeated 4 times :) I understood that is because I am trying to join two tables with a common column, but still I haven't resolved my problem.

Comment: @vibs2006 please read my last note above, that is the reason why I tried to postpone the inner join.

Answer (score 0):

`INNER JOIN` clause must come before `where` and `group by` clauses:

```
SELECT TOP (10000) MAX (PlanID) AS [PlanID]
  ,MAX (InfoID) AS [InfoID]
  ,MAX (Comp) AS [Comp] 
  ,MAX (CompName) AS [CompName]
  ,MAX (GuidID) AS [GuidID]
  ,MAX (Object) AS [Object]
  ,OrderID
  ,CurrencyShort

  FROM [dbo].[Plant] as Plimp         
  INNER JOIN [dbo].[Order] as Ord
  ON Plimp.InfoID = Ord.InfoID

 WHERE [CompName] NOT LIKE 'BB%'
  and InfoID < 196673
  and InfoID > 185679
  GROUP BY (InfoID)
  order by InfoID desc
```

Comment: thank you, but it still does not solve my problem. Please have a look at my new result above.

Answer (score 0):

`Join` will come before `Where` and `Order by`, all the table joins will be present together in `From` Clause

```
FROM   [dbo].[Plant] AS Plimp
       INNER JOIN [dbo].[Order] AS Ord
               ON Plimp.InfoID = Ord.InfoID
WHERE  [CompName] NOT LIKE 'BB%'
       AND Ord.InfoID < 196673
       AND Ord.InfoID > 185679
GROUP  BY ( Ord.InfoID )
ORDER  BY Ord.InfoID DESC
```

Comment: If I follow yor instructions, I get: Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
Ambiguous column name 'InfoID'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
Ambiguous column name 'InfoID'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
Ambiguous column name 'InfoID'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Ambiguous column name 'InfoID'.   Note that this column is present in both the tables. Maybe that is the reason why I get the error?

Comment: @gmt - Because it is present in both the tables, so we to need to qualify it by using alias names.. check now

Comment: still not luck, please check my result above

Comment: @gmt Post the table schema.. Error message is very clear, there is no column called `InfoID` present in either of your tables

Comment: I think the problem is the opposite: InfoID is present in both the tables! If I replace ",MAX (InfoID) AS [InfoID]" with ",[InfoID]" I get:   Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Ambiguous column name 'PlanningInfoID'.

Comment: Ok, I am getting there: ",[InfoID]" column in "[dbo].[Plant]" originally presents duplicates, which I eliminate in the original table with " WHERE [CompName] NOT LIKE 'BB%' ". The problem here is that this condition is after the Inner Join! But I can't put it before, or I get an error anyway... Maybe I should use some parenthesis?